# Embed an ASPX page into an ASCX Control?

Tags: asp.net, ascx

Is it possible to embed an ASPX page into an ASCX control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

That would be a bit like building a car into the passenger seat.

-- Edit:

To be clear, you could potentially consider various ways of grabbing the content (such as actually requesting it) and then including it in your ASCX control, but it would, in general, but a quite "backwards" approach. What are you trying to do?

Comment: LMAO. That made my day. Anyway, that's how you say, you can't.

Comment: I want to integrate of an aspx page into an aspx page at a specific region

Comment: @uhu: Right, that isn't any more detail than you initially provided. The typical approach here would be to make the page you want to integrate itself a UserControl, and then embed it.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible with iframe.

.ascx control code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Control.ascx.cs" Inherits="Project.Control" %>
<iframe id="ctrlIframe" runat="server" src="path/to/your_aspx_file.aspx"></iframe>
```

Iframe there links to aspx page.

You would also need to resize iframe to fit your aspx in ascx control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function IFrameFitContent() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("<%= ctrlIframe.ClientID %>");
        var bHeight = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        var dHeight = iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        var bWidth = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
        var dWidth = iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollWidth;
        var height = Math.max(bHeight, dHeight);
        var width = Math.max(dWidth, bWidth);
        iframe.height = height;
        iframe.width = width;
    }
</script>
```